# How to use a logical operator over a boolean array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, logical-operators

I have duly searched the documentation and SE, but have failed to find out the solution: given an arbitrarily large vector of boolean values, how to return e.g. the logical AND of given values?

I would expect something like:

```
and([1 1 1])  -->  1
```

(since `true && true && true` gives 1). Of course, it is not valid syntax.

My aim is to find the fastest way to compare two binary vectors of the same size and return 1 if they are identical and 0 if not. Since the element-wise `and` returns a vector if used on two vectors hence the title question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`all()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/all.html):

```
result = all(a == b);
```

Comment: And for the operator `OR` use the function `any`.